# JS ERROR Error when trying to execute simple http Request

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

I am trying to interact with a Gateway and wanted to try the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/request module.

The code I am trying to execute:

```
export class OAuthAccessor {

    //some stuff

    public static createOAuthAccessToken() {
        this.makeCall();  //this line 11
    }

    private static makeCall() {
        var request = require('request');
        request.post({
            uri: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Accept-Language": "en_US",
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            auth: {
                'user': this.clientID,
                'pass': this.secret,
                // 'sendImmediately': false
            },
            form: {
                "grant_type": "client_credentials"
            }
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log("error = " + error);
            console.log(body);
        });
    }

}
```

Error:

> file:///.../OAuthAccessor.js:11:30: JS ERROR Error: Could not find module 'request'. Computed path '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ACA260DA-C0FD-4373-8822-447422199751/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EE654C43-B629-4817-929F-F4E52DA1A99F/IPGIntegration.app/app/tns_modules/request'

My Package.json:

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.IPGIntegration",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "3.1.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "3.1.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/request": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.2",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
    "tns-core-modules": "~3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.25.0",
    "babel-types": "6.25.0",
    "babylon": "6.17.4",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.4"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
                "./node_modules/@types/request/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms",
        "**/*.aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

What I did:
create a new Project with the typescript template

```
tns create my-app-name --template typescript
npm install typescript (version 2.3.4)
npm install @types/request
```

I already tried reinstalling typescript and types/request module and node_modules folder, as well as other versions of typescript. Did I miss something when installing that module?

Comment: shouldn't you require your dependency at the top of the file?

Comment: This is the first time I make use of .. TypeScript at all - I don't know. You mean above the class declaration? - If that's what you meant, that did not do the trick. If that was not what you mean, please clarify it for me :)

Comment: yeah,the very top of the file

Comment: Sadly the same error, since he says "could not find module" I think that I missed something when installing - or perhaps an import?

Comment: `@types/request` is a definitions package, it will provide autocomplete for the `request` package. Perhaps you want to install `request` too?

Comment: I did `npm install request --save` - still getting (almost) the same error:    _file:///app/tns_modules/tough-cookie/./lib/cookie.js:32:18: JS ERROR Error: Could not find module 'net'. Computed path '/Users/.../Devices/ACA260DA-C0FD-4373-8822-447422199751/.../Application/0405EA45-7D21-4244-B3ED-556CF3D7EBBF/PayPalIPG.app/app/tns_modules/net'.
Aug  2 13:00:35 Admins-iMac com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.ACA260DA-C0FD-4373-8822-447422199751.launchd_sim[1030] (UIKitApplication:org.nativescript.PayPalIPG[0xd4a][1052][3680]): Service exited due to Segmentation fault: 11_

Comment: That is expected. `request` being a NODEJS module, depends on modules present in the nodejs platform, most of which are not implemented in NativeScript.

Comment: So do you know a way how i can use it? Or am I supposed to use XMLHttpRequest-Module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `request` npm module for it is a nodeJS module depending on built-in node functionalities, like the [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) module.

In order to make http requests you can use the cross-platform modules' `http` implementation as shown in the NativeScript docs article - http://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http

If you need to make https requests you could use the nativescript-https plugin - https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-https

Comment: Thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to

```
require('@types/request')
```

Comment: Now I am getting a Segmentation fault, so that seems to do the trick :) Thank you!

Comment: Alright, sadly that did not do the trick. Whenever I execute `var request = require('request');`  I keep getting the following error:    

com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.ACA260DA-C0FD-4373-8822-447422199751.launchd_sim[1030] (UIKitApplication:org.nativescript.Projectname[0xcd5b][1052][2586]): Service exited due to Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: surely a nativescript error, try updating your dependencies,i found npm install tns-core-modules@latest --save in this issue https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/issues/142

Comment: Thats what I also found, that did not do the trick sadly. Also setting my typescript version to 2.3.4 did not work

Comment: When I do not execute that line, everything works perfectly. So it seems to be related to that line of code.  -  shall I open a new Post for that questions since it seems to be another one?

Comment: by any chance,are you using Hello World NativeScript Angular2 Template ?

Comment: I am working under the typescript template (`tns create app-name --template typescript`) - might be integrated? Not sure about that

Comment: Why would you require a definitions package? They are used for the sole purpose of providing hints to the developer, they contain no functionality.